# Am I doing this while loop correctly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to plot the logarithm of twelve tone equal temperament on a scale of hertz.

Is this while loop that breaks in the middle the best way to iterate all of the audible notes in the scale? Could I do the same thing more accurately, or with less code?

I do not want to use a for loop because then the range would be defined arbitrarily, not by the audible range.

When I try to use "note > highest or note < lowest" as the condition for the while loop, it doesn't work. I'm assuming that's because of the scope of where "note" is defined.

```
highest = 20000
lowest = 20

key = 440
TET = 12

equal_temper = [key]

i = 1
while True:
  note = key * (2**(1/TET))**i
  if note > highest or note < lowest:
    break
  equal_temper.append(note)
  i += 1

i = 1
while True:
  note = key * (2**(1/TET))**-i
  if note > highest or note < lowest:
    break
  equal_temper.append(note)
  i += 1

equal_tempered = sorted(equal_temper)
for i in range(len(equal_temper)):
  print(equal_tempered[i])
```

The code returns a list of pitches (in hertz) that are very close to other tables I have looked at, but the higher numbers are further off. Setting a while loop to loop indefinitely seems to work, but I suspect there may be a more elegant way to write the loop.

Comment: ``((2**(1/TET))**i)`` could be simplified to ``2**(i/TET)``.

Comment: Having a `while True` loop is almost always incorrect.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @RayButterworth , I get a "NameError"

Comment: @DYZ , what would be a better alternative here? In what scenario is it the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, you actually *know* the number of iterations! At least you can calculate it by doing some simple math. Then you can use a list comprehension to build your list:

```
import math 
min_I = math.ceil(TET*math.log2(lowest/key))
max_I = math.floor(TET*math.log2(highest/key))
equal_tempered = [key * 2 ** (i / TET) for i in range(min_I, max_I + 1)]
```

Comment: Excellent! I do not immediately understand the math here, but I will take a closer look at that code to see if I can comprehend it enough to use it. Thankyou @DYZ !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the piano key formula:

```
freq_n = freq_ref * sqrt(2, 12) ** (n − a)
```

The reference note is A4, 440 Hz and 49th key on the piano:

```py
def piano_freq(key_no: int) -> float:
    ref_tone = 440
    ref_no = 49
    freq_ratio = 2 ** (1/12)
    return ref_tone * freq_ratio ** (key_no - ref_no)
```

Then you can do things like:

```py
print(piano_freq(40)) # C4 = 261.6255653005985
print([piano_freq(no) for no in range(49, 49+12)]) # A4 .. G#5
```

Based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies

Comment: Yes, that looks like the same math that I am using. However, I don't understand how that will make this code better.